# Creates copy of existing record with foreign key association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following models

```
public class ProfessionalEmploymentRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Program Program { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Add(ProfessionalEmploymentRecord p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Check which program is being considered
        p.Program.ID = GetProgramId(p.Program.Name);
        p.Role.ID = GetProfessionalId(p.Role.Name);
        db.ProfessionalEmploymentRecords.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(p);
}
```

When using Add() I end up with two records (difference being the primary key ID) with the same Role.Name and Program.Name in Roles and Progams tables, respectively.

My goal is to have ProfessionalEmploymentRecord p to have an association with a single (unique) Program and Role per record p.

Edit:

An Example

If I let ProfessionalEmploymentRecord p be 
p.Role.Name = "Analyst"
p.Program.Name= "A"

Then the Add() function creates a new record in ProfessionalEmploymentRecords which contains RoleId = 2 and ProgramId = 2

In the Roles and Programs tables I end up with
Roles
ID  Name
1   Analyst
2   Analyst

Program
ID  Name
1   A
2   A

To simplify the question, why does Add function create entries into two other tables?

Comment: p in Add(p) is an input from a razor view Create.

Comment: This looks like duplicate operation. If p has a Program already, why do you need to assign an ID for it? What id the code in GetProgramId and GetProfessionalId?

Comment: Amiram, Get*Id looks like private int GetProgramId(string Name) { try { int ID = (from p in db.Programs where p.Name.Equals(Name) select p.ID).First(); return ID; } catch { //throw new Exception("No ID found for Name " + Name); return 0; } }

Comment: I have commented out the Get*Id statements to let EF figure out the correct assignment however it did not work either.

Comment: There is no such thing as ASP.NET MVC Code First. There are ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework Code First. That is absolute different and non related technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference of ProfessionalEmploymentRecord  in the Program and Role class.

```
public class Program
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ProfessionalEmploymentRecord ProfessionalEmploymentRecord { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ProfessionalEmploymentRecord ProfessionalEmploymentRecord { get; set; }
}
```